# Two Divs beside each other. One grows the container the other takes the available space

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid, web-frontend

My Problem is, that I want to have two divs next to each other inside a container and the height is dictated by the second/right div. My thought was to have a container with those two divs.

- Left gets 100% height of its container (never grows larger than the available space)
- Right grows as much as it wants/needs to fit its content (auto)
- through which the container grows through which left grows.

How can I achieve this?

This codepen gives the structure and shows that my solution obviously doesn't work. Maybe display:flex is the problem? Should I use grid? Do I need any of this? How can this be done?

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #338811;
}

.left {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #888833;
}

.right {
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #885588;
}
```

https://codepen.io/kruben/pen/poVEzWG

Comment: Please Clarify your question. Unable to get it, Correct me if I am understanding wrong. On basis of your query, you need equal height columns inside the container Wrapper. Right?

Comment: I want the overall size to be dependent on the .right div. The .left is not allowed to get larger than the .right